# Making register page log you in after registration is complete

Tags: php

I have this registration form that a user fills out and it sends to another page that adds the information in my database. Is there a way that after the person registers I can send the username and password to the sign-in page and  it logs them in automatically?
this is the code that adds into my database after a user has registered:

```
require "connection.php";

session_start();

if ($_POST['firstname'] != "" && $_POST['lastname'] !="" && $_POST['email'] != "" && $_POST['username'] !="" && $_POST['password'] !="")
{
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $query1="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' ";
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$firstname);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$lastname);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email);




    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query1)
    or die(mysqli_error($conn));  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['er_firstname'] = $firstname;
        $_SESSION['er_lastname'] = $lastname;
        $_SESSION['er_email'] = $email;
        header("Location: index.php/?a=1");
    }



    else {
        unset($_SESSION['er_firstname']);
        unset($_SESSION['er_lastname']);
        unset($_SESSION['er_email']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, password, username) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password', '$username')";


    $data = mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    header("Location: index.php/?a=2");

    }

}


?>
```

And this is my login code that when I user normally enters there username and password to log in:

```
<?php 

session_start();
$username = $_POST['username']; //either username or email
$password = $_POST['password'];


if($username=="" || $password == "")
{
    header("Location: index.php");

}

require "connection.php";

if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);


    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' OR email = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


    if($data) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1 ) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

            header("Location: http://home");

        }
        else {
            header("Location: index.php/?i=1");
            exit();
        } }

    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }

}
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Please enter a email and password";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

So is there a way to send add.php to login.php, I tried switching the add.php header location to login.php but it didnt work.

Comment: Ummmm, if you don't want to use prepared statements, you need to escape your variables ***before*** you use them in a query (`$username`). And to answer your question, set the same session variables and redirect to the same page as when you login.

Comment: make a login function and pass required parameter username and password to do the login

Comment: You could create a unique key column in your DB and then store this inside a session or a cookie. You could then include some form of check on each of your login pages which query's this unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bypass the entire login screen. You can just apply login logic into your registration processing.

This would involve adding three lines of code by the looks of it.

```
        $_SESSION['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

        header("Location: http://home");
```

Comment: I put this in my login.php along with the other code right?

Comment: No, this would be in the php file that adds your user after filling in the form.

Comment: Ok after what exactly? instead of the `header("location/index.php?a=2")`

Comment: Okay I managed to get it to work I changed it a bit but thanks!